What is that relation betweet coherence and supersolidity?
While reading an article about supersolidity I came across the phrase "an ordered crystal structure with a
phase coherence that allows for partial superfluid flow
through the solid ". What is meant phase coherent in that system and what is that relation betweet phase coherence and partial superfluid flow?

According to my ideas, firstly, superfluidity of liquid is not a Bose condensate. Superfluidity can be explained only by studying the potential relief and collective diffusion in ordinary liquids. Then it becomes obvious that the superfluid phase has a linear structure and is more like strings, delocalization occurs only in one direction. The coherence of the wave function occurs only along the line, and does not have a volumetric character as is accepted in modern theory. Collective movements of atoms occur in the solid phase at low temperatures. About 30 years ago, I attended a seminar by Russian academician Goldansky, who spoke about such experiments. Movements of atoms in a solid at low temperatures can occur only if the solid is in a disordered glassy state. In this case, one-dimensional movements can occur, as in a liquid, which are described by the Frenkel-Kontorova crowdion theory. I think this is the basis of the state of supersolids.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
